# Viewing downvoted answer on deleted question

Tags: feature-request, answers, down-votes, deleted-questions

For one of the questions I answered, I saw it was downvoted. The question was removed as well, so I couldn't view the post to see why my answer was downvoted.

In such circumstances, how can I know the reason behind down voting?  Just so that I can improve my answer in the future.  Should the people who answered a question, be able to see their even after the post is deleted?

Comment: Downvotes and deletion are two very different things; it seems you're equating them here.  Which are you talking about here, down votes, or a deleted post?

Comment: Whether the post was removed or not, seeing it isn't necessarily going to help you understand why a person down-voted.

Comment: @servy I'm talking about answer that downvotes inside a post that being deleted.

Comment: If you really want to know the reason why you were downvoted, and that's actually your question, then the answer is simple; you can never *know* why you were downvoted.  You can guess, or we could guess, or some other reader can guess, but at the end of the day you can never *know*.

Comment: @aaron-bertrand I think when we're down voting a question we always get some advice to give an explanation about why we are down votes that question, I think this was a good culture if we came here to delevoping our self and those people who seeking for help. And if you doesn't give any explanation, perhaps you don't know why you are down votes the question or answer

Comment: There [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes?rq=1) was good actually

Comment: The fact remains that [most people don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes).

Comment: But I think you all are right, I just think PERHAPS person that down votes mine would left a note a comment of what I miss.

Comment: Answers to bad questions seems to get downvoted just for being an answers to bad questions. I don't say it's fair, but on the other hand discouraging answering bad questions may help to discourage asking them in the first place (why to ask what nobody will answer?). And if question is, for example, opinion based, you may get downvotes from people with different opinion on your answer. And so on.

Comment: @molot I don't think that's how it should work for a better solution. I think many bad question born from newbie Stack networking. In that case, should we just try to help them to be better?

Comment: I encourage helping them. But they also need a reason to make their questions better. And what reason is there, when they have an answer?